# Recalculating String Length Within Loop

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, for-loop

The following code is supposed to double each letter in a particular string (ex. 'hello' to 'hheelllloo') but the function is returning the "list index out of range" error to all string inputs. The problem is obviously caused by a conflict between the ever increasing length of the string with each subsequent insert and the constant value of the length of the array calculated only at the beginning of the for statement.

```
def double_char(str):
    l = list(str)
    for i in range (0,len(l)+1):
        l.insert(2*i, l[2*i])
    return l
```

I wanted to figure out if there is some way to continuously calculate the length of the list with each for statement so the insert command will function properly while still keeping the initial range of i fixed.

Comment: Use a while loop instead, manually increment `i` and compare to `len(l)`. Or use regex: `re.sub("(.)", "\\1\\1", str)`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `str` as a variable name.  `str` is a python built in method.

Answer (score 3):

Why cannot you use simple [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for this? Example -

```
>>> def double_char(s):
...     return ''.join(c+c for c in s)
...
>>> double_char('hello')
'hheelllloo'
>>> double_char('hellobye')
'hheelllloobbyyee'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an empty String, and append to it:

```
>>>def double_char(word):
...    l = ""
...    for i in word:
...        l += i*2
...    return l

>>> double_char("hello")
'hheelllloo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Anand's answer is likely the most pythonic. If you are newer to python, readability may be important as well. This would work too:

```
def doubleString(word):
    newWord = ""
    for letter in word:
        newWord += (2 * letter)
    return newWord
```